# How to stop distracting navigation bar animation in Xamarin.Forms/Android?

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, tabs

I have a TabbedPage with four tabs in Xamarin.Forms. The four tab pages each inherit from a common ContentPage with an AbsoluteLayout. When I push to this TabbedPage on Android, the new navigation bar momentarily appears about one-third of the way down the screen then rapidly animates to its proper position at the top of the screen, before other screen elements are displayed. It's very distracting, and even happens (without any text) if I do not set a title at all. Does not happen on iPhone.

How can I prevent this animation?

Edit: Here is a video showing the problem at 0:02, 0:24 and 0:40 : https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1rHxS_rcVEr8sPC0yujcZf34XvLJ7yJ2K?usp=sharing

Comment: I can set animation to false in the Push - that removes the problem, but creates another problem - a flash of white screen that I can't remove

Comment: Can you upload relevant screenshots or videos to illustrate your problem?I don't quite understand your problem.

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT Will try to get a video, a bit tricky

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT Have added a video showing the problem.

Comment: Could you please post a basic demo to github or onedriver so that we can  help you better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the navbar animates from bottom to top of the screen and it stopped midway because I was doing too much on the UI thread in OnAppearing.

Adding a 200ms delay in OnAppearing was one way to avoid it.